# Monogame - Load SpriteFont using .spritefont file without using the Pipeline Tool

Tags: monogame

There is a way to load a sprite-font **without using the Monogame Pipeline tool?**

I am creating a Game-Engine using Monogame, i cant use the Monogame Pipeline tool because the way that Game-Engine manage the Content Files is different, and it needs to read the source file, not the .xnb file that Monogame Pipeline tool create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a way to load a `SpriteFont` without the need of MGCB, and to make it better.

You'll need to use [SpriteFontPlus](https://github.com/rds1983/SpriteFontPlus). It generates `SpriteFont` objects dynamically from normal image files.

Comment: i will try that latter

Answer (score 0):

No, the SpriteFont content type starts as instructions to the content pipeline to convert a specific font at a specific size (in pt) into a set of textures for every UTF-8 character. Since a .SpriteFont doesn't contain any textures, it has to be compiled by the content pipeline to be imported in MonoGame as a SpriteFont.

Comment: Well, but there is an way for compiling the .spritefont files to .xnb using a executable separated?, like when i want to compile something, i just call <name_of_the_executable> $file_to_compile$ $output$?

Comment: If you're gonna go through that trouble, you're better off using the MGCB, because it it will compile the content and copy it to your output folder for you on each build. It's a lot less troublesome that way.

Comment: well, i need to not use the MGCB because i am creating a complete GameEngine.

Comment: Then you'll need to learn by yourself how to create texture data from the [multiple font formats available](https://fileinfo.com/filetypes/font) which all vary sgnificantly.

Here's my advice: Focus on making a game, not an engine. MonoGame is a great base for your game, and you'll be better off taking what's included and work with it. If MGCB is what grinds your gears the most, I suggest you give [NoPipeline](https://github.com/Martenfur/NoPipeline) a try. But from what I gather, you're biting off more than you can chew.

Comment: The problem is: i am actualy creating a Game Engine not a Game

Comment: Like I said, you are biting off more than you can chew. Making a game engine is very hard and requires knowledge of trigonometry, matrices and linear algebra, alongside understanding of common file formats and their standards, plus how to use graphics libraries like OpenGL or DirectX for rendering and writing shaders, and also targeting specific platforms such as Android, IOS, x86, ARM, etc.

Diving into those subjects should keep you occupied for a while until you get tired of it. However, this is completely out of scope from your original question.